# Pg dump when username contains @ symbol

Tags: postgresql, azure-sql-database, pg-dump

My company moved to managed Postgres on Azure. Azure requires an "@" in the Postgres username, hence my connection string is now (note: it has two @s):

```
MY_DB=postgres://somename@someserver_in_short:somepassword@someserver_in_long:5432/dbname?sslmode=require
```

When doing `pg_dump MY_DB > file.sql`, I get an error:

```
pg_dump: error: connection to database "dbname" failed: invalid integer value "somepasswordsomedbnamemixedstring" for connection option "port"
```

I assume the confusion arises from the fact that the connection string has now two @s.
Is there an easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Solution from my colleague: replace @ with %40 in username.